# PHP form not inserting into mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, post

hi guys thanks if you can tell me what error i need help guys thanks for help me

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";   $username = "root"; $password = ""; 
    $dbname = "kurd";
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","","kurd") or die ("not connect data base");
    mysql_select_db("kurd") or die ("no found table"); 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $password =_POST['password'];
        $query =" INSERT INTO kurdstan (name,lastname,password) VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$password')";
        if(mysql_query($query)){
            echo "<h3>THANKS FOR INSERT DATA GOOD LUCK</h3>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post an actual question and show what work you've already done.

Comment: <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "kurd";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","","kurd") or die ("not connect data base");
mysql_select_db("kurd") or die ("no found table");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query =" INSERT INTO kurdstan (name,lastname,password) VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$password')";
if(mysql_query($query))
{
echo "<h3>THANKS FOR INSERT DATA GOOD LUCK</h3>";}
}
?>

Comment: do not post code in comments, edit your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - please read How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In your code add an `else` to,

```
if(mysql_query($query)){
   echo "<h3>THANKS FOR INSERT DATA GOOD LUCK</h3>";
}
```

resulting in,

```
if(mysql_query($query)){
   echo "<h3>THANKS FOR INSERT DATA GOOD LUCK</h3>";
}
else {
   echo 'MYSQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
}
```

and you will probably see an error instead of your message which should help you to track down the problem.

**NOTE**

The `mysql` extension is now depreciated, you should use `mysqli` http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. You should also read up on SQL injection - your data needs escaping before being used in a query string.